# al deshabilitar un boton este pierde el look de bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

tengo este textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbid" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

form-control es una clase de bootstrap para que el textbox tenga el look de bootstrap, si deshabilito el textbox desde codigo usando

```
tbid.Enabled = false;
```

el textbox pierde el look de botstrap, despues de inspeccionar el codigo vi que es reemplazada por la clase aspNetDisabled.

como puedo evitar que esto pase quiero que el boton siga manteniendo el look de bootstrap aun deshabilitado.

Comment: lo mejor seria ver la razon por la que se elimina su clase

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas facil que encontre para hacerlo fue poniendo esto

> .Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled"

en lugar de esto

> .Enabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

Que te parece poniendo en tu archivo `CSS` la clase `aspNetDisabled` y en ella le pones el css que desees (igual al de la clase `form-control`), pero a cada etiqueta le asignas `!important` al final. Ejemplo:

*Tu clase `form-control` actual en tu archivo `CSS`:*

```
.form-control {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ahora pones en tu mismo archivo `CSS` la clase `aspNetDisabled`:

```
.aspNetDisabled {
    color: red !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Lo anterior hará que se reemplaza el css de la clase por el que tu quieras.

Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

El **atributo Asp.Net correcto** a establecer en tu control es `CssClass`.

El atributo que tienes establecido `class`, a pesar de ser un atributo válido, interfiere con el engine de Asp.Net al renderizar tu control y no mezcla bien el atributo propio "class" de Asp.Net con el tuyo.

Si eso no soluciona el problema, puedes establecer la clase por defecto disabled para los controles de servidor Asp.Net en el Global.asax en el métod que se ejecuta al iniciar la app:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebControl.DisabledCssClass = string.empty;
}
```